# Why Is Add-In Mailbox Requirement Set 1.6 Not Supported In Outlook 2019?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've created a very simple manifest.xml file for an Outlook Add-In. When I use the manifest validator, the validator claims that the Add-In will not work on Outlook 2019 (retail or volume license):

Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store:

- Outlook on Windows (Microsoft 365)
- Outlook on Mac (Microsoft 365)
- Outlook on the web

As far as I can tell, this manifest specifies Requirement Set 1.6 of Mailbox which is supported on any version of Outlook 2019 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview). If I change the requirement set to 1.5, Outlook 2019 becomes available. I should add that our test Outlook 2019 application does not show the Add-In as available for installation.

Can anyone tell me why the validator is doing this?

The manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>5cab1898-a3f0-4d55-9613-70e646caa635</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="dummy1"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.6"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
</OfficeApp>
```

I expected the manifest to support Outlook 2019 and yet it doesn't!

Comment: Could you provide your Outlook client version when you get a chance? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a question relating to an installed Outlook client. It's a question relating to the manifest validator which appears to be giving the wrong result. You can run the manifest validator without having Outlook installed. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest